# How to run windows commands on Ubuntu through Wine?

Tags: command-line, windows, wine

I just installed Windows Office 2016 on Ubuntu through `wine`. I wanted to check if it is Volume Licensed version or retail version. So I tried following command as suggested [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/troubleshoot/licensing/determine-office-license-type?tabs=windows):

```
oem@PC-Ubuntu:~/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/Office2016/drive_c/Program Files/Microsoft Office/Office16$ wine cmd /c cscript OSPP.VBBS /dstatus
```

But simply does not output anything. I tried the same on winconsole, but still didnt get any output:

[image]

Why is this so? Am I making any mistake while running Windows command on Ubunutu through wine?

Comment: Honestly, not sure if that specific command works. But you should be able to check the license details in the "About" section of any app.

Comment: Didnt get why some command (`ospp.vbs` here) wont output anything.

Comment: Maybe it works with VB support installed in the same container, maybe not. Wine is not and universal solution for Windows software. Some do run fine, some run partially, with issues, some do nothing at all.

Comment: Is not running on Windows that is the answer.

Comment: You mean am not getting output because its not running actual Windows and there is something broken when run through wine?